# Invalid type "any" of template literal expression in React Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a slider component in which I keep getting this error : Invalid type "any" of template literal expression in React Typescript at const fillWidth variable. I'm unable to figure out solution for this, can someone please help me with this

```
import React from 'react';
import './slider.scss';

export default class Slider extends React.Component {
    outputUpdate = (e) => {
        const { value } = e.target;
        const delta = {
            capacity: value,
        };
    }

    render() {
        const {
            id,
            min,
            capacity,
            displayCapacity,
            step,
        } = this.props;

        const attributes = {
            id,
            name: id,
            value: displayCapacity,
            min,
            max: capacity,
            step,
            'aria-valuemin': min,
            'aria-valuemax': capacity,
            'aria-valuenow': displayCapacity,
            'aria-orientation': 'horizontal',
            type: 'range',
            className: 'slider my-3',
        };
        const fillWidth = capacity ? (`${displayCapacity > capacity ? capacity : displayCapacity}` - min) / (capacity - min) * 100 : 0;
        return (
            <div className="slider-container">
                <input
                    ref={this.sliderInput}
                    {...attributes}
                    onChange={e => this.outputUpdate(e)}
                    onInput={e => this.outputUpdate(e)}
                />
                <div className="slider-range" />
                <div className="slider-note">
                    <span>
                        <Currency value={min} decimals={0} />
                    </span>
                    <span style={CamelCaseStyles(Text16Right)}>
                        <Currency value={capacity} decimals={0} />
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

}

Comment: One red flag is that you are subtracting something from a *string*. Template literals are strings.

Answer (score 0):

You doing the calculations as a template literal (type string) which I am assuming is the problem. If some of the variables you are using are strings you can coerce them into numbers and do the calculations after. Also giving the `fillWidth` variable a type of number will ensure that it expects that.

```
const fillWidth: number = capacity ? (Number(displayCapacity) > Number(capacity) ? Number(capacity) : Number(displayCapacity) - min) / (capacity - min) * 100 : 0;
```

This should work for you, however this is just to show you an example. You could optimize this to not repeat as much.